# Error 404 when uploading file to Grav in the dropzone using nginx

Tags: nginx, upload, digital-ocean, cms

[repost from the [grav forum](https://discourse.getgrav.org/t/error-404-when-uploading-file/24483)]

I’m using Grav with Nginx. My issue is that I keep getting an error when I upload a file in a form.

[dropzone error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRtIQ.png)

I checked the Nginx error log file, and it seems the problem is where it’s trying to temporary upload the file.

`2023/12/20 12:46:40 [error] 42123#42123: *540 open() “/home/grav/www/html/fr/test.json/task:file-upload” failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: localhost, request: “POST /fr/test.json/task:file-upload HTTP/1.1”, host: “xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx”, referrer: “http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/fr/test”`

However, the path `/home/grav/www/html/fr/test.json/` doesn’t exist in my Grav arborescence.

If it helps this is what the console shows :

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC8ZM.png)

With the issue being this part of the  `form.vendor.js`
in  `/home/grav/www/html/user/plugins/form/assets`

```
{
key: "submitRequest",
value: function(e, t) {
   e.send(t)
}
```

I’ve looked around but can’t seem to find a solution online.

Using this answre from @pamtbaau :

*Can nginx write to /tmp?*

*Using Apache, when I do a chmod -w /tmp I get the following error:*

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) typography.json/task:file-upload:1`

*The error happens when dropping a file in the Dropzone.*

*By the way, `typography.json/task:file-upload:1` does not exist. It is a virtual path which is caught by the Form plugin when dropping a file in Dropzone. Form plugin will then save the file in `/tmp/form/....` When submitting the form, Form plugin will fetch the temp file and store it in the `destination` of the File field.*

I tried giving writing priviledges,and tried switching ownership of `/home/grav/www/html/tmp`    from `grav:grav` to `root:root`, but the issue persists

Thank you : )